# Glassfish - high CPU usge

Tags: performance, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, cpu-usage

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.1 web profile in production envirnoment and it's eating too much CPU.
Here is server settings: Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit, Intel Xeon 8core @ 3,2GHz, 8GB ram.
I'm using JDK 1.7u2 64bit. Glassfish JVM settings:

```
<jvm-options>-XX:+UseCompressedOops</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Xmn1g</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Xss128k</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:+UseParallelOldGC</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Xmx3g</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:+DisableExplicitGC</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-d64</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:PermSize=256m</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Xms3g</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:MaxPermSize=256m</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:+AggressiveHeap</jvm-options>
```

I've also tune some options according to http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2009/11/27/putting-glassfish-v3-in-production-essential-surviving-guide/
Running for few hours or 1 day Glassfish use 15% to 40% CPU, someties 90% and application dosen't respond.

```
[#|2012-02-03T10:30:46.837+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GRIZZLY0023: Interrupting idle Thread: http-thread-pool-80(32).|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:55.074+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=41;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GRIZZLY0023: Interrupting idle Thread: http-thread-pool-80(41).|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.665+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureWriteOpen(SocketChannelImpl.java:249)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:440)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:108)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushChannel(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:326)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:398)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:282)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:898)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:167)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.filters.GzipOutputFilter$FakeOutputStream.write(GzipOutputFilter.java:223)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.finish(GZIPOutputStream.java:169)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.close(DeflaterOutputStream.java:238)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.filters.GzipOutputFilter.recycle(GzipOutputFilter.java:186)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.recycle(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:417)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.finishResponse(ProcessorTask.java:817)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.postResponse(ProcessorTask.java:750)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:726)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.665+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureWriteOpen(SocketChannelImpl.java:249)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.665+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:440)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.665+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:108)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.665+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:76)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.665+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushChannel(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:326)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.665+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:398)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.665+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:282)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.665+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:898)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.681+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:167)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.681+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.filters.GzipOutputFilter$FakeOutputStream.write(GzipOutputFilter.java:223)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.681+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.finish(GZIPOutputStream.java:169)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.681+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.close(DeflaterOutputStream.java:238)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.681+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.filters.GzipOutputFilter.recycle(GzipOutputFilter.java:186)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.681+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.recycle(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:417)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.681+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.finishResponse(ProcessorTask.java:817)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.681+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.postResponse(ProcessorTask.java:750)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.681+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:726)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.681+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.681+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.681+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.681+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.681+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.681+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.681+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.681+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.681+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.681+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.681+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:30:56.681+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=138;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:31:00.440+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GRIZZLY0023: Interrupting idle Thread: http-thread-pool-80(38).|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:33:49.170+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GRIZZLY0023: Interrupting idle Thread: http-thread-pool-80(11).|#]

[#|2012-02-03T10:33:57.235+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GRIZZLY0023: Interrupting idle Thread: http-thread-pool-80(16).|#]
```

Edit: I solved the problem, there is bug in Glassfish gzip compression, so I turned it off.
http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/glassfish-301-gzip-problem-threads-apparently-spinning-100-cpu-use

Instead I would use this: http://www.servletsuite.com/servlets/gzipflt.htm to compress content.

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently a bug in GlassFish 3.1.1 and 3.1.2. The [JIRA issue for it](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18705) contains patches which might help.

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by an infinite loop in Java code which is referenced by an expression in a view. [Take a tread dump](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/TakeThreadDump.html) of your application server when it is running and gets this problem, and search for the problematic thread(s) like your `http-thread-pool-80(32)` and `http-thread-pool-80(41)` -- if your application server is spending all its time on one section of your application code, it may well be an infinite loop (or something else that causes that code to be run more often than it should).

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem, even though we did not use GZIP. After a while (and under high load) our logs would fill up with

`GRIZZLY0023: Interrupting idle Thread: http-thread-pool-28080(34)`

We managed to resolve this for Glassfish 3.1.1 by upgrading grizzly to a version found in Glassfish 3.1.2.2. Read more about it at http://thumbtribe-it.blogspot.com/2012/10/grizzly0023.html

Comment: Yeah, I'm also getting CPU devouring behavior on my dev machine. The funny thing is, the GF instance is NOT under load. In fact, I can leave it running with NO applications deployed, and it will do this after a certain amount of time (sorry, I have not tried to time it yet). This link MIGHT be relevant for some: http://gregorbowie.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/java-glassfish-v3-high-cpu-and-memory-usage-locked-threads-death/